# being+past participle without is/are - what is the rule?

Tags: passive-voice, continuous

*English words being used in conversation.*

*being used* - what is the rule?

If it is the passive voice (Continuous), why it is used without *be*, like
*English words are being used in conversation*.

If it is not passive voice, then what is the rule? I can not to find in Google.

Comment: *English words being used in conversation* is a ***noun phrase*** (not a sentence), so it doesn't really have a "tense / voice". It's equivalent to *English words **that / which are** being used in conversation*. As opposed t your alternative *English words **are** being used in conversation*, which is a perfectly valid sentence with a subject *(English words)* and verb *(are being used)*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Reinstate Monica thank you very much. Now I see. Did I understand correctly that "English words being used in conversation" more like "English words used in conversation", but first phrase - continious tense?

Comment: Your ***being*** and my ***which / that are*** are both just optional elements that don't really make any difference to the meaning of the entire noun phrase. The "head noun" of the noun phrase is ***words***, initially qualified by the adjective ***English***. What *follows* the head noun is called an ["adjectival phrase"](https://examples.yourdictionary.com/adjective-phrase-examples.html) (compare *Cowboys **riding into the sunset** were in the final scenes of many movies* in that link with *Many words **being used in English today** came from Latin,* or with your own example).

Answer (score 2):

Some terminology before the answer:

**Phrase** is a group of words that are meaningfully related and complete a single role in a sentence. Each phrase has a **headword** which is a main word in a phrase (I don't know how to explain it precisely, but I think it isn't difficult to understand this intuitively). The phrases are classified depending on their headwords - for example, if the phrase's headword is a noun, it is a noun phrase, if the headword is a verb, the phrase is a verb phrase, and so on.

So, now the answer itself:

First of all I would like to say that when someone says "participle", he(she) most likely means either *present participle* which is presented in the language by the V-ing form of a verb (single verb), or *past participle* which is presented by the V3 form of a verb (also single verb).
There are different kind of uses of participles in English, and one of them is that **we can use participles and participle phrases *instead of relative clauses*** - both present participles and past participles (and corresponding phrases) can be used in such a way. For example, consider the following sentences:

- The man standing over there is my uncle.
- The man that is standing over there is my uncle.

In this example present participle phrase "standing over there" is used instead a relative clause "that is standing over there".

The same is true for past participles. For example, look at the following sentences:

- The chicken eaten by the children was contaminated.
- The chicken that was eaten by the children was contaminated.

In this example the past participle phrase "eaten by the children" is used instead a relative clause "that was eaten by the children".

Up to this point, the two things you should understand are:

1. When we say "participle" in 90 percent of cases we  mean either present participle (V-ing form of a verb) or past participle (V3 form of a verb).
2. We can use both present and past participles (and corresponding phrases, i.e. phrases that have a past participle as their headword and phrases that have a present participle as their headword) instead of relative clauses to make our sentences shorter.

**Here starts the main part of this answer:**
Not only present participles and past participles can be called participles. There are also *compound participles*, like, for example "being done", "having done" or even "having been doing" that are used almost exactly like "usual" participles, but they are formed not with one word (as is the case with the present and past participles) but with combinations of some verbs. There are different kinds of compound participles and I won't enumerate them here because it is not strongly related to your question. So, for example, "being done" is an example of a compound participle that is formed by the scheme (being + V3 form of a main verb).
And these compound participles (and phrases which have compound participles as their headwords) can be used to replace relative clauses TOO. For example, consider the following sentences:

- The details being prepared right now in the factory will be used tomorrow.
- The details that are being prepared right now in the factory will be used tomorrow.

In this example the compound participle "being prepared right now in the factory" is used instead of the relative clause "that are being prepared right now in the factory".

So, now you should understand the following:

- Although in most of the cases "participle" means either "present participle" or "past participle", it can mean "compound participle" too (although this happens rarely, it is possible).
- All kinds of participles (present participle, past participle and compound participles) and corresponding phrases can be used to replace relative clauses. There are special rules regarding which relative clauses can be replaced by present participle and corresponding phrases, which ones can be replaced by past participle and corresponding phrases, and which ones can be replaced by compound participles and corresponding phrases. But the key point is that it is possible to get rid of relative clauses using participles.
  Returning to your question - in your example:

> English words being used in conversation.

words "being used in conversation" are used to make sentence more short. The "full sentence", I mean, expressed with a relative clause, would be:

> English words that are being used in conversation.

So, we can say, that **here the participle phrase "being used in conversation" is used instead of a relative clause "that are being used in conversation"** Note that the headword of this participle phrase is a compound participle *being used*.

Hope my answer will help you.